# Rails 4: Filter data using form in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, filter

I have some data and I'd like to give the user the ability to filter this data by selecting a given date range.  I can manipulate the data by supplying the date range in the controller using my own filter:

```
def self.filter_chart(date_start = 2.years.ago.to_s, date_end = Date.today.to_s)
    real_start = date_start.to_date
    real_end = date_end.to_date
    part_1 = PotentialClient.where('created_at >= ?', real_start)
    part_2 = part_1.where('created_at <= ?', real_end)

    return part_2
end
```

`@clients = PotentialClient.filter_chart(2.days.ago.to_s, Date.today.to_s)`

...but I want the user to be able to select a start date and end date and submit the form to show data for that date range.  How do I construct a form / function to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this in my current app.  Here is the form view.

```
<%
  if params[:start_date].present? && params[:end_date].present?
    start_date = Date.parse(params[:start_date])
    end_date = Date.parse(params[:end_date])
  else
    start_date = Time.zone.today - 30.days
    end_date = Time.zone.today
  end
%>

<%= form_tag('', class: 'form', method: :post) do %>
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="start_date" value="<%= start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>">
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="end_date" value="<%= end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Run report">
<% end %>
```

And here is your reports controller.

```
def create
  if params[:start_date].present? && params[:end_date].present?
    start_date = Date.parse(params[:start_date])
    end_date = Date.parse(params[:end_date])
  else
    start_date = Time.zone.today - 30.days
    end_date = Time.zone.today
  end

  start_date = Time.zone.parse(params[:start_date]).beginning_of_day
  end_date = Time.zone.parse(params[:end_date]).end_of_day
  report_data = PotentialClient.where('created_at >= ?', start_date).where('created_at <= ?', end_date)
end
```

Comment: The thing is I'm not trying to `save` a new entry, I just want to change the data being shown.  Would this answer do that?